# How to select a dl tag with all child in c#

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

I have a problem to select all `dt` and `dd` from the blow HTML table

```
<dl class="Grid Grid--multicol Grid--2col:40em Grid--4col:60em">
    <div class="Grid-cell u-flex u-flexOne u-flexRow">
        <dt> Item ID:</dt>
        <dd class="u-weightSemibold u-paddingL5px">72547664</dd>
    </div>
    <div class="Grid-cell u-flex u-flexOne u-flexRow">
            <dt> License:</dt>
            <dd class="u-weightSemibold u-paddingL5px">
                <a class="u-linkDodgerBlue js-infoLicenseString" href="" target="_blank">Standard</a>
            </dd>
    </div>
    <div class="Grid-cell u-flex u-flexOne u-flexRow">
            <dt> Usage:</dt>
            <dd class="u-weightSemibold">Commercial<span class="TooltipQuestionMark"></span></dd>
    </div>
    <div class="Grid-cell u-flex u-flexOne u-flexRow">
            <dt> Required Plugins:</dt>
            <dd class="u-weightSemibold u-paddingL5px">None</dd>
    </div>
    <div class="Grid-cell u-flex u-flexOne u-flexRow">
            <dt> Creation Tool:</dt>
            <dd class="u-weightSemibold u-paddingL5px">Autodesk</dd>
    </div>
    <div class="Grid-cell u-flex u-flexOne u-isHidden:0-60em"></div>
</dl>
```

I write this

```
            i = 0; doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dl").Where(x => x.HasClass("Grid")).FirstOrDefault().SelectNodes(".//div").ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                result.Items.Add(new DownloadItem { Name = "specs-title", Index = i,    Type = DownloadItemType.Text, Value = x.SelectNodes(".//dt").FirstOrDefault().GetText() });
                result.Items.Add(new DownloadItem { Name = "specs",       Index = i++,  Type = DownloadItemType.Text, Value = x.SelectNodes(".//dd").GetText() });
            });
```

The above code just grab the first row
`Item ID:` | `72547664`
whats my problem to list all `dt` and `dd` information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem of your code is that at first time when you want to grab all `dl` elements with class `Grid`, you take only first of that type of DOM elements with the method `FirstOrDefault()`.

```
i = 0; doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//dl").Where(x => x.HasClass("Grid")).SelectNodes(".//div").ToList().ForEach(x =>
            {
                result.Items.Add(new DownloadItem { Name = "specs-title", Index = i,    Type = DownloadItemType.Text, Value = x.SelectNodes(".//dt").FirstOrDefault().GetText() });
                result.Items.Add(new DownloadItem { Name = "specs",       Index = i++,  Type = DownloadItemType.Text, Value = x.SelectNodes(".//dd").GetText() });
            });
```

you have to remove `FirstOrDefault()` to take all the elements which suits to your demand.